# Android добавление данных из RecyclerView в SQL базу данных

Tags: java, android, sql

Ребят сталкнулся с проблемой такой, получаю данные через ретрофит, вывожу через RecyclerView и мне надо сохранить это в базу данных, но что-то не получается, что я делаю не так? Получаю список стран, для начала хочу понять как хотя бы названия сохранить.

**Cоздание:**

```
public class DataBaseCreator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DB_NAME = "Countries";
    public static int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static class CountriesColumns implements BaseColumns{
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "name";
        public static final String NAME = "country";
    }

    private static String CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES = "CREATE TABLE " + CountriesColumns.TABLE_NAME +
            " (" +
            CountriesColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            CountriesColumns.NAME + " TEXT" +
            ");";
    public DataBaseCreator(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Основная работа с базой (здесь столкнулся с проблемой, не пойму что писать в скобках, там вопрос я написал):

```
public class DataBaseMasters {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseCreator dbCreator;

    private static DataBaseMasters instance;


    private DataBaseMasters(Context context) {
        dbCreator = new DataBaseCreator(context);
        if (database == null || !database.isOpen()) {
            database = dbCreator.getWritableDatabase();
        }

    }

    public static DataBaseMasters getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DataBaseMasters(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addCountry(Countries countries) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DataBaseCreator.CountriesColumns.NAME, countries.name);
        database.insert(DataBaseCreator.CountriesColumns.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        //TODO DataBaseCreator.UserColums  alt+enter and do static, and after i use just TABLE_Name and others
        Log.d("addCountries", database.insert(DataBaseCreator.CountriesColumns.TABLE_NAME, null, cv) + "");


    }

    public List<Countries> getAllUsersQuery() {

        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseCreator.CountriesColumns.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null,
                null, null, null);

        List<Countries> list = new ArrayList<>();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            Countries countries = new Countries(что писать здесь?);

            countries.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseCreator.CountriesColumns.NAME));
            Log.d("getAllUsers", "name: " + countries.name);
            list.add(countries);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }

}
```

**Класс стран:**

```
public class Countries implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String capital;
    String region;
    String subregion;
    int population;
    int image;
    public List<String> languages;
    String[] timezones;

    public Countries(String name, String capital, String region, String subregion, int population,int image, List<String> languages, String[] timezones) {
        this.name = name;
        this.capital = capital;
        this.region = region;
        this.subregion = subregion;
        this.population = population;
        this.image = image;
        this.languages = languages;
        this.timezones = timezones;
    }
```

**Main** так же столкнулся с проблемой:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    Retofit.getCountries(new Callback<List<Countries>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(final List<Countries> countries, Response      response) {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                list.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(countries, new OnItemClickWatcher<Countries>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View v, int position, Countries item) {
                        Intent mintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        Countries countries1 = countries.get(position);
                        mintent.putExtra("Key", countries1);
                        startActivity(mintent);
                    }
                }));

                DataBaseMasters.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addCountry(что писать здесь?);


                List<Countries> query = DataBaseMasters.getInstance(MainActivity.this).getAllUsersQuery();
                Log.d("query", "size: " + query.size());
            }
```

Comment: Лучше всё-таки код и лучше в таком количестве, чтобы было легко воспроизвести.

Comment: добавил код, вместо репозитория